Django ManifestStaticFilesStorage throwing Value Error
I am attempting to ensure that the cache is refreshed whenever I spin up a new instance in Django. I have implemented the following custom storage class to disable the strict handling of manifest files:
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import ManifestStaticFilesStorage

class NonStrictManifestStaticFilesStorage(ManifestStaticFilesStorage):
    manifest_strict = False

This is used in conjunction with the setting:
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "myapp.custom_storages.NonStrictManifestStaticFilesStorage"

While everything appears to function correctly, I encounter a ValueError when a file does not exist, despite having set manifest_strict = False. This error was not expected under these circumstances.
Could someone assist me in debugging this issue? As a temporary solution, deleting the problematic file resolves the error, but this is prone to future errors. For instance, if someone inadvertently removes a CSS file while cleaning up the code, it could disrupt the backend server, which must be avoided.

I had a similar problem and ended up by implementing
class ForgivingManifestStaticFilesStorage(ManifestStaticFilesStorage):

    manifest_strict = False

    def hashed_name(self, name, content=None, filename=None):
        try:
            result = super().hashed_name(name, content, filename)
        except ValueError:
            # When the fille is missing, let's forgive and ignore that.
            # logger.warning
            result = name
        return result

You may stille have 404 errors.

This did work. Indeed, I do see 404 errors on the client side trying to fetch the non-existing file but it does not throw a 500 error at runtime. Thanks!
